# About positive eigenvectors of $-\Delta$ on $\mathbb R^N$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Im interested whether there exists positive solutions of
$$
(*)\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=\lambda u\\ u\in H^1(\mathbb R^N)
\end{cases}
$$
for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. Here, we hve $-\Delta=-\sum\partial_i^2$.

On the one hand, it es well known that in case $N=1$ the equation $-u''=\lambda u$ has the general solution
$$
\begin{cases} a\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+b\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x) & \text{ if }\lambda>0\\
at+b & \text{ if }\lambda=0\\
ae^{\sqrt{|\lambda|}x}+be^{-\sqrt{|\lambda|}x} & \text{ if }\lambda<0
\end{cases}
$$
But obviously non of these are square integrable. So I claimed

> There is no nontrivial and positive solution of $(*)$ for $N\leq 4$.

I would appreciate if you can verify if my proof it correct or point out if I missed a point.

**Proof:**

Let be $\lambda\geq 0$ and $u\in H^1(\mathbb R^N)$ a positive solution of $(*)$. Then we get $-\Delta u=\lambda u\geq 0$. In this case, there are theorems which claims for $N\geq 4$ that $u$ has to be constantly zero.

So, we have to consider the case $\lambda<0$. A solution of $(*)$ is a critical point of the function $I(u):=\frac12|\nabla u|_2^2-\frac{\lambda}2|u|_2^2$, where $|~\cdot~|_2$ denotes the $L^2(\mathbb R^N)$-norm. But then we get
$$
0=\nabla I(u)[u]=|\nabla u|_2^2-\lambda|u|_2^2=|\nabla u|_2^2+|\lambda|\cdot|u|_2^2.
$$
But this yields $u\equiv 0$.

**End of the proof**

Ok, how about the eigenvectors of $-\Delta$ for $N\geq 2$? The conclusion is, that the eigenvectors of $-\Delta$ have either sign changes or they are not in $L^2(\mathbb R^N)$. Are there some eigenvectors explicitly known?

Comment: The Laplacian has no eigenfunctions in $L^2$. This can be easily verified using Fourier transform. See also this closely related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790401/how-to-prove-the-spectrum-of-the-laplace-operator/790543#790543 and probably many others on this site.

Comment: @MaoWao Nice, I see. So, assume $f$ is an $L^2$ eigenfunction to an eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, then using Fourier transformation gives $(|\xi|^2-\lambda)\hat f=0$, which implies $\hat f=0$ and then $f=0$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.